# Syntax error in inserting new record to Ms Access Database using C# windows form

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, oledb

I have a form where user can type and select from multiple controls like, dropdown list, date time pickers, textboxes, checkboxes etc. On a button click event, I wrote the following procedure to INSERT the new record in MS Access Database:
Code:

```
private void InsertNewRecord()
    {


        txtLastUpdated.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(MTSConn))

        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())

            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"Insert Into Incoming_T (DocFrom, CntrTeam, To, ReferenceNo, Subject, Review, Type, DocDate, RcvdDate, ProjectRef, DIMSNo, DIMSLink, SnrEng,    MailStatus, Comments, LogRegID, RegisteredBy, UpdatedBy, LastUpdated, ForInf, ForReview, ForApp, ForComnt, ForHndlng, ForAct) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 100) { Value = cbxFrom.SelectedValue });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 20) { Value = cbxTo.SelectedValue });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 100) { Value = cbxTo.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = txtReference.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 200) { Value = txtSubject.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 1) { Value = cbxReview.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 10) { Value = cbxDocType.SelectedValue });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Date, 8) { Value = dtpDocDate.Value });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Date, 8) { Value = dtpRcvDate.Value });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 20) { Value = cbxProject.SelectedValue });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 15) { Value = txtDIMS.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = txtDIMLink.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 10) { Value = cbxSnrEngr.SelectedValue });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 20) { Value = cbxStatus.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = txtComments.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Integer, 4) { Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtRegID.Text) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = txtRegBy.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = txtUpdatedBy.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Date, 8) { Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtLastUpdated.Text) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Boolean, 1) { Value = Convert.ToBoolean(chkInf.Checked) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Boolean, 1) { Value = Convert.ToBoolean(chkRw.Checked) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Boolean, 1) { Value = Convert.ToBoolean(chkApp.Checked) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Boolean, 1) { Value = Convert.ToBoolean(chkComm.Checked) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Boolean, 1) { Value = Convert.ToBoolean(chkHandl.Checked) });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Boolean, 1) { Value = Convert.ToBoolean(chkAct.Checked) });


                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Recored Inserted Successfully!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting Syntax error while Inserting the record to Access Database. I also try this code also but same problem:

```
private void InsertNewRecord()
    {
        txtLastUpdated.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(MTSConn))

        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())

            {
                .
                .
                .
            }
       }
```

My Form Look like this:
[image]

Is I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

"Type" is a [reserved word in Access](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Learn-about-Access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) so you will have to wrap it in square brackets in the query:

```
Insert Into Incoming_T (DocFrom, CntrTeam, To, ReferenceNo, Subject, Review, 
        [Type], DocDate, RcvdDate, ProjectRef, DIMSNo, DIMSLink, SnrEng,
        MailStatus, Comments, LogRegID, RegisteredBy, UpdatedBy, LastUpdated,
        ForInf, ForReview, ForApp, ForComnt, ForHndlng, ForAct) 
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you included the **text** of the actual error you receive in your question.

Comment: Thank you stuartd, but it says "The connection not established." I tried to open the connection before Adding the parameters, but still have problem. wrapping [Type] field inside brackets has no effects on the this error.

Comment: In your question you said you received a **syntax** error.

Comment: YES, but when I changed the using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) to using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(MTSConn)) the Error message changed to "Connection property has not been Initialized"

Comment: It looks like you're getting that error because you're not assigning the connection to the command object - if you use `cmd = new OleDbCommand()` rather than `cmd = conn.CreateCommand()` then you have to tell the command what connection to use - `cmd.Connection = conn`.

Comment: After adding cmd.Connection = conn; now it says "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." :)

Comment: Does this work within Access? `SELECT DocFrom, CntrTeam, To, ReferenceNo, Subject, Review, 
        [Type], DocDate, RcvdDate, ProjectRef, DIMSNo, DIMSLink, SnrEng,
        MailStatus, Comments, LogRegID, RegisteredBy, UpdatedBy, LastUpdated,
        ForInf, ForReview, ForApp, ForComnt, ForHndlng, ForAct FROM Incoming_T`

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with this simple SELECT statement within Access.

Comment: Actually there was problem in Access Field name "To", which is also a RESERVED word, so by putting brackets around [To] solved the problem. There no syntax error now.. a little data types conversion errors which are fixed accordingly. Thank you stuartd - Appreciate.